# Browser back button negates CSS changes done by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a form that displays different select lists based on a previous select list.

HTML

```
<select name="college" id="college" onchange="show_majors()">
                <!-- <option value="-">-</option> -->
                <option value="COE">College of Engineering</option>
                <option value="CBE">College of Business and Economics</option>
                <option value="CS">College of Science</option>
                <option value="CHSS">College of Humanities and Social Sciences</option>
                <option value="CIT">College of Information Technology</option>
                <option value="CEDU">College of Education</option>
                <option value="CL">College of Law</option>
                <option value="CFA">College of Food and Agriculture</option>
</select>

        <div id="COE_MAJORS" class="majors">
            <p><strong>Major:</strong></p>
                <select name="COE_major" id="COE_major" onchange="show_clusters()">
                    <option value="OTHER">-</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div id="CBE_MAJORS" class="majors">
            <p><strong>Major:</strong></p>
                <select name="CBE_major" id="CBE_major" onchange="show_clusters()">
                    <option value="OTHER">-</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        .....
```

CSS

```
.majors {
   height: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function show_majors() {
                var college = document.getElementById("college");
                college = college[college.selectedIndex].value;
                var majors = document.getElementsByClassName("majors");
                for(var i = 0; i < majors.length ; i++) {
                    majors[i].style.height = "0px";
                }
                if (college != "-") {
                    document.getElementById(college + "_MAJORS").style.height = "auto";
                }
            }
</script>
```

Now the problem is after selecting a college and a major then pressing the submit button (which redirects to another page). When I press the back button of the browser, the last selected college is still selected but the majors DIV box is reset to 0 height. How can I have it display the major div box for that corresponding college when the user presses the back button, so it does not reset

Comment: You could store the state in a cookie or local storage and restore it based on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the restored selection in the window's `load` event.

Since you already have a function that updates the page based on the current selection, the simplest solution is to run it when the page loads:

```
<script>
addEventListener('load', show_majors);
</script>
```